# Connect to Windows7 machine and print document

Tags: networking, printing, samba

I have Windows7 on one machine.  Ubuntu 12.10 on another.  I have a printer connected to the Windows7 machine.  Basic network home lan setup.  The brother printer works fine on windows 7.  I setup "share printer" on the windows7 machine.  And I want to be able to print from the Ubuntu machine.

On Ubuntu:
If I select "New Printer" from the system settings and then Network Printer and the Windows Printer Via SAMBA, I can't find the Windows7 printer.  I can find the machine but not the printer.

I even try to manually enter in:  smb://workgroup/server/brotherprinter  and that still won't work in terms of printing.

When I see the "smb browser", I see the workgroup but not the printer.
The screen just hangs trying to refresh the devices.
...

What can I do to print to that printer?

Comment: What is your printer  name and model? Do you able to share file between ubuntu and windows 7 via samba?

Comment: Brother 2040.  It hasn't even gotten that far.  The shared printer shows up in the network folder under Windows7.  Just can't see it from Ubuntu.  Maybe I should try to connect to a folder from ubuntu first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1868207) will help to solve your problem. Read it carefully.

Comment: Basically it.  I figured it out and there are little things you don't think about.  I thought Ubuntu was detecting the ip of the windows machine but it wasn't.  It was listed in the browsing network but I guess that is meaningless.  I went ahead and just added the ip address of the windows machine to the /etc/hosts file.  I also had to use an upper-case hostname.  After doing that, I could find the printer on the network through the "add network printer steps", I entered credentials and everything worked fine.  Also, I went ahead and used a printer name without spaces.

Comment: Glad to hear that it works. :)